# Meteor Mupx with Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: meteor, nginx, docker, reverse-proxy

I'm setting up multiple virtual servers using docker and managing the routing with an nginx reverse proxy (https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/).

I already have a couple other dockers (for mysql and wp)

I would like to use mupx to deploy thanks to it's ease of use (https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/tree/mupx#), though it is require to provide a port and defaults to 80 (which conflicts with nginx).

Here are the relevant elements from the mup.json

```
"servers": [
    {
      "host": "111.111.111.111",
      "username": "root",
      "pem": "path/to/key",
        "env":{
            "VIRTUAL_HOST":"subdomain.domain.com"            
        }    
    }
  ],
...
  "env": {
    "ROOT_URL": "http://subdomain.domain.com"
  }
```

Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can change the port of the app to avoid the conflict

```
  "env": {
    "PORT": 80, // change to anything?
```

Comment: I haven't tried it, but won't that lead to me having to change the nginx settings to forward to the correct port? If so that would defeat the ease of use of the nginx docker package (where you simply have to set the virtual_host when creating a new docker instance)

Comment: @Victor.dMdB it's possible that `mupx` will export the port you specify (`use it as -p in docker` automatically so that config in the answer is perfectly fine. It will be available in the host with that port.

Comment: It worked! I had forgot to update the DNS to remove CNAMEs and add 
an "A Record" instead. Also I had to change the root url to the IP.

Comment: Has anyone figured out how to keep everything on port 80 using nginx? Right using this way mentioned above allows for http://site-two.com:3000 but not both http://example.com and http://site-two.com